# FV calculation works in immediate window but shows mismatch error when in normal code

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing an assingment on FV calculation and it is very simple but the thing is the code is showing mismatch error and I have no idea. I checked all the nooks and corners but still the same. I have tried doing the code in immediate windows and it works. I checked the works of my friends and the same values with same declarations but theirs work. I am very confused and I need help.

```
Sub CalculateFV()
    Dim PValue As Currency, pmt As Currency, PMT_Type As String, PMT_Freq As Integer
    Dim N_Years As Integer, rate As Double, Cmpd_Freq As Integer
    Dim EffPrdRate As Double, Nper As Integer, FValue As Currency
    

    PValue = PV_FVCal.Value
    rate = Rate_FVCal.Value / 100
    pmt = PMT_FVCal.Value
    
    If PMTFreq_FVCal.Value = "Monthly" Then
        PMT_Freq = 12
    ElseIf PMTFreq_FVCal.Value = "Quarterly" Then
        PMT_Freq = 4
    ElseIf PMTFreq_FVCal.Value = "Semi-Annually" Then
        PMT_Freq = 2
    ElseIf PMTFreq_FVCal.Value = "Yearly" Then
        PMT_Freq = 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select Compounding Frequncy!")
    End If
    
    If OptionButton5.Value = True Then
        PMT_Type = "End"
    ElseIf OptionButton6.Value = True Then
        PMT_Type = "Beginning"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Select End or Beginning of period for PMT!")
    End If

    N_Years = Nyears_FVCal.Value
    
    If CmpdFreq_FVCal.Value = "Monthly" Then
        Cmpd_Freq = 12
    ElseIf CmpdFreq_FVCal.Value = "Quarterly" Then
        Cmpd_Freq = 4
    ElseIf CmpdFreq_FVCal.Value = "Semi-Annually" Then
        Cmpd_Freq = 2
    ElseIf CmpdFreq_FVCal.Value = "Yearly" Then
        Cmpd_Freq = 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select Compounding Frequncy!")
    End If
    
    EffPrdRate = (1 + rate / Cmpd_Freq) ^ (Cmpd_Freq / PMT_Freq) - 1
    Nper = PMT_Freq * N_Years
    If PMT_Type = "End" Then
        
        Debug.Print FV(0.0004758, 120, 100, 10000)
        'FValue = FV(EffPrdRate, Nper, pmt, PValue, 0)
    ElseIf PMT_Type = "Beginning" Then
        FValue = FV(EffPrdRate, Nper, pmt, PValue, 1)
    End If
    
    FV.Text = FValue
       
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Debug.Print FV(0.0004758, 120, 100, 10000),
FValue = FV(EffPrdRate, Nper, pmt, PValue, 0)  Both lines throw error. it is fine up until then

Comment: `Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.FV(0.0004758, 120, 100, 10000)`

Comment: `FV.Text = FValue`... this looks suspicious. What are you referring to with `FV` here?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you download the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and take a look at the code inspections.

Comment: Thank you scott craner. It worked